# How do I prevent multiple instances of a process(NPAPI plugin) from running in Posix?

Tags: macos, posix, semaphore, named-pipes, npapi

On windows, I solved this issue by creating a named semaphore. If plugin 1 crashes while holding the semaphore, the semaphore is released. But its not the case with Posix (on Mac), where the semaphore stays alive. Since, sigaction will not release the SIGKILL on the semaphore, I have to abandon it.

What is my best option.

named pipes, ports, message queue, remote function execution?

Comment: This sounds a little unusual. What problem are you actually trying to solve here? Do you need to broker access to one common process/device/.../something?

Comment: No, The npapi plugin runs a video and we don't want to have to instances of the video player running.

Comment: Ah, so you don't actually want to prevent plugins running, but not have them do something. Any potential issue with basing this on short time-outs, where another takes over if a timestamp wasn't updated in `N` ms?

Comment: I would like to prevent multiple instances of the plugin running. I thought of timeout but then the plugin which is running would have to constantly send out a msg(or something) indicating that it is alive and running. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: [This thread](http://osdir.com/ml/darwin-kernel/2009-03/msg00005.html) has some bits on a related scenario, `SEM_UNDO` with System V style sounds promising. Don't you have to poll state in intervals on the waiting side(s) anyway to ensure proper shutdown of the instances?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using a open() call available in POSIX. Apparently, file descriptors for a process are released by the OS even the process is terminated by SIGKILL

```
Constructor()
{
   m_fd = open(filePath, O_CREAT | O_EXLOCK | O_NONBLOCK);
   if (m_fd == -1)
    {
        throw exception;
    }
    ...
}

Destructor()
{
    if(m_fd != 0)
    {
        close(m_fd);
    }
    ...
}
```